# __get_item__ in Dataset class giving keyerror: Python

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torchvision

So I am writing this dataset class. And in `__get_item__` this is giving me this error:

```
>   0
>   {}
> 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-65-263240bbee7e> in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 main()
> 
> 3 frames <ipython-input-64-2b81d181af45> in __getitem__(self, idx)
>      12       print(idx)
>      13       print(self.dataset[idx])
> ---> 14       fname = os.path.join(self.data_dir+'/images/', self.dataset[idx]['image'])
>      15       #if os.path.exists(fname):
>      16       img = Image.open(fname).convert('RGB')
> 
> KeyError: 'image'
> 
>
```

One sample index of the dataset is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {939: {'image': 'COCO_train2014_000000163939.jpg', 'texts': {0: 'the right half of a keyboard'}}
```

```
class RefCOCOgDataset(Dataset):
 def __init__(self, dataset, transform=None, data_dir='dataset/refcocog'):
  super(RefCOCOgDataset, self).__init__()
  self.data_dir = data_dir
  self.transform = transform
  self.dataset = dataset
  print(self.dataset)


 def __getitem__(self, idx):  
  data_item = {i: torch.tensor(v[idx]) for i, v in self.dataset.items() if idx in 
  self.dataset.keys()}    
  print(idx)
  print(self.dataset[idx])
  fname = os.path.join(self.data_dir+'/images/', self.dataset[idx]['image'])
  #if os.path.exists(fname):
  img = Image.open(fname).convert('RGB')   
  image = self.transform(img)['image']
  data_item['image'] = image.permute(2, 0, 1).float()
  data_item['texts'] = self.dataset[idx]['texts']
  print(data_item[idx])
  
  return data_item


def __len__(self):
  return len(self.dataset)
```

My question is, how to map my dataset correctly so that it doesnt give me keyerror and the dataset gets loaded in the dataloader correctly? I want the `idx` iterate through my `dataset` dict (for example being idx=939) for correct mapping like the code I have written of image and texts. Is it possible? Sorry I am not clear on how this iteration of `__get_item__` works. Would someone please shed some light onto this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't get that error for the sample item you show, it has an `image` key. What do you want to do for items with no `image`?

Comment: @Barmar Hi. Thanks for commenting. No thats not an issue. Becaused datasets have been preprocessed to have such indexes like the sample in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You revealed a subset of what is happening, instead of offering a
[reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Apparently some dataset `ds` had a `939` key.
But up in a hidden portion of the call stack
you dereferenced `ds[0]`.

```
 def __getitem__(self, idx):  
  data_item = {i: torch.tensor(v[idx]) for i, v in self.dataset.items() if idx in 
  self.dataset.keys()}    
  print(idx)
  print(self.dataset[idx])
```

So `0` is passed in, and it corresponds to an empty `dict`.
The pair of prints report this, when they say `0` and `{}`.

Given that, it is hardly surprising that
attempting to dereference `self.dataset[0]['image']`
would report KeyError.

---

Decompose your problem
[further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle),
write one or more unit tests,
and show us how the new code behaves in your use case.
As presented, the specification is unclear.